# Conditionally set a object property

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dynogels

Its possible to remove the .where clause if queryString is null?

I have tried ternary operator in the middle of expression, but doesn't work.

Also the equals expression dont allow: null, undefined or empty String.

```
CashierHistory
            .scan()
            .where('userId').equals(path['userId'])
            .where('status').equals(queryString['status']) # remove all this line in case of queryString['status'] is null
            .limit(10)
            .startKey(queryString)
            .exec(function (err, acc) {
                if (err == null) {
                    console.log(acc);
                    return cb(null, Api.response(acc));
                } else {
                    console.log(err['message']);
                    return cb(null, Api.errors(200, {5: err['message']}));
                }
            });
```

**Edit**: I am using [Dynogels](https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels) (An ORM for Dynamodb)

Comment: What is this library or similar you're using?

Comment: break into 2 parts before/after the conditional, assign the left-side to a var, add the IF, continue the chain using the named var

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just edit my question

Comment: @dandavis I dont like to do it, because I will need to do a lot of if/else, since I gonna have 4 conditions, then will be 16 if/else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dandavis said you can break your query into two parts

```
var query = CashierHistory
        .scan()
        .where('userId').equals(path['userId']);

if (queryString['status']) {
    query = query.where('status').equals(queryString['status']);
}

return query.limit(10)
        .startKey(queryString)
        .exec(function (err, acc) {
            if (err == null) {
                console.log(acc);
                return cb(null, Api.response(acc));
            } else {
                console.log(err['message']);
                return cb(null, Api.errors(200, {5: err['message']}));
            }
        });
```